# Object detector with multiple datasets

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I am interested in building a yolo detector with trained on multiple datasets where each dataset has it own detection head. It is a multi-task learning approach. I am not sure how to  convert the yolo detector architecture to support multiple head.

I came across the following projects, however I need your help to implement similar approach.

https://github.com/xingyizhou/UniDet

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-16-6963-7_27

Answer (score 0):

This approach has some difficulties. First, in article you sent they use two-stage detection model with separate classification "branches". In the same time YOLO is one-stage detector and is **fullyconvolutional**, that means there are no fullyconnected layers, and class predictions (1d) are taking from the whole 3d-tensor (see the image).
[image: yolo tensors]

You can take a look at [YOLO9000](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242.pdf) paper, the model was trained on detection and classification datasets at the same time - only loss function was changing.